# .NET Asynchronous Client / Server Sockets

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, iis

I have set up an Asynchronous Client / Server sockets using the exact sample code provided by Microsoft.

Client Socket

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

// State object for receiving data from remote device.
public class StateObject {
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient {
    // The port number for the remote device.
    private const int port = 11000;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = 
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = 
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = 
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.
    private static String response = String.Empty;

    private static void StartClient() {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            // The name of the 
            // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("host.contoso.com");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect( remoteEP, 
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            Send(client,"This is a test<EOF>");
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

            // Release the socket.
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client) {
        try {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            } else {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1) {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data) {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args) {
        StartClient();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Server Socket

```
    using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject {
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener {
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public AsynchronousSocketListener() {
    }

    public static void StartListening() {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true) {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept( 
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener );

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content );
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                Send(handler, content);
            } else {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data) {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }


    public static int Main(String[] args) {
        StartListening();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I am running it all locally through Visual Studio it works fine, I am able to pass my data with out any issues. The issue comes up when I have this Client Socket code running on a simple ASP.NET webpage I've created and set up to run on IIS. When the code is running on IIS it is being picked up by my Server Socket (which is running on my machine) and on the first call, the data is passed fine. On every other call thereafter the Server Socket (while debugging) gets to calling ReadCallBack() where I then do stuff with the data, it just jumps over it... No errors occur, no nothing. Then the server socket goes back to sitting idle with the "Waiting for connection" line on the console.

Has anyone encountered an issue similar to this? To sum it up, when running on IIS only one Client to Server call can be made, with Data succesfully passed. After that first call it never jumps into ReadCallBack.

Through my debugging I have noticed one thing, and that is the Socket.Available field is 0 instead of its usually values (between 8-10 depending on size of data in bytes). Even when I hardcode data to be sent, it is still seen as 0 when debugging on the Server Socket.

I apologize if I have only managed to confuse people,

cheers.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest executable.  There is a bin/debug and bin/release folder in the project.  Check Timestamp on the exe in both files to make sure you are using latest.  Looking at your code I suspect you are getting data packets with zero bytes.  You need to execute : new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state); even when you get an empty packet.  Move this code outside the IF statement.

Comment: After the first call to the server socket (which works) it never even enters that ReadCallBack() method. While debugging it enters the AcceptCallBack which in turn calls the ReadCallBack through new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack) BUT if this is t he second attempt at calling the server socket, it simply will not enter ReadCallBack. It does not error or anything, it just seemingly does nothing. This does not happen though if its not running off of IIS

Comment: After every EndReceive() you need to issue a new BeginReceive(), otherwise, you will not get any more receive messages.  In your code when you get a zero byte message you are not issuing a new BegfinReceive().  Different server will can behave differently with zero byte messages due to timing.  So I don't care if it runs on a different PC.